# Would a magic charm that has to be refueled by nonmagical weather energy be able to be recharged via a spell that changes the weather?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dragon-of-icespire-peak

I read the *Dragon of Icespire Peak* campaign book, and saw that the *Charm of the Storm* has to be refueled by nonmagical (in the sense that a spell that deals lightning damage can't be used, and similarly a dragonborn's lightning breath weapon) lightning energy striking the lightning rod 3 times. I thought, **would a spell that changes the weather to a thunderstorm count as 'natural'?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### That works (and it doesn't specify non-magical).

> The altar recharges when the lightning rod on the roof (see area T8) is struck by three bolts of lightning from a storm and channels that energy down into the altar. Lightning from other sources doesn’t count.

It doesn't actually specify "non-magical," just that it must be "bolts of lightning from a storm." As long as you have something that counts as a storm — magically encouraged or otherwise — its lightning bolts would suffice to recharge the altar.

Lightning Bolt doesn't work, but it's not because it's magical: it's because it's not originating from a storm. A dragonborn's breath weapon also doesn't work, whether or not it's from a book that classifies it as magical, as it's originating from a dragonborn rather than a storm.

Comment: Pay attention that a dragonborn's breath weapon is not magical.

Comment: @NautArch Yes, but by the way is written it seems that Shivers consider the breath weapon magical, which is not.

Comment: @Eddymage Since Fizban (I think) there are dragonborns whose breath weapon is specifically called out as being "magical" in their description, unlike their PHB counterparts.

Comment: @Pepijn Oh, you're totally right! But those are optional rules, maybe it is better to specify it in the answer...

Comment: Tweaked the last paragraph to separate out the variably-magical dragonborn breath.

Comment: I would be referring to dragonborn from the PHB.